# Wilcard Search LIKE %e.name% from INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do a wildcard search on a value from a joined item. Ie.

```
 SELECT
    (
        SELECT
            count(*)
        FROM
            user_contacts e
        WHERE
            ece.user = 1 AND 
            (
                e.name LIKE '%u.lastname%'
                OR
                e.name LIKE '%u.firstname%'
            )
    ) as friends_count,

    u.user_id,
    u.firstname,
    u.lastname
  FROM
    users u
```

But it doesnt work. I could instead do:

`e.name LIKE u.lastname`

That would work, but that would not include the wildcard %% which I need.

Any ideas?

Comment: That you want to do this is a clear indicator that your database design is incorrect. You should not ever consider joining on a wildcard in a  database. If the name is part of the other field, you should pull it out once to a separate field.  Or you should ask the user to put the data in separately not in a field with something else. It is a poor practice to ever store more than one piece of informatino in a particular records for a particular field. So never store a comma delimited list, something that is separated by hyphens, first and last name in the same field, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could concatenate it.

```
e.name LIKE CONCAT('%', u.lastname, '%')
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use the right syntax for concatenation for MySQL:

```
 SELECT (SELECT count(*)
         FROM  user_contacts e
         WHERE e.user = 1 AND 
               (e.name LIKE concat('%', u.lastname, '%') or
                e.name LIKE concat('%', u.firstname, '%') 
               )
         ) as friends_count,
       u.user_id, u.firstname, u.lastname
 FROM users u;
```

Answer (score 0):

`e.name LIKE '%' || u.lastname || '%'`

Beware that mysql requires you to enable the standard concat operator. See PIPES_AS_CONCAT